# Extracting path coefficients of piecewise SEM (structural equation model)

Tags: r, piecewise, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I'm constructing a piecewise structural equation model using the piecewiseSEM package in R (Lefcheck - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/piecewiseSEM/vignettes/piecewiseSEM.html)

I already created the model set and I could evaluate the model fit, so the model itself works. Also, the data fits the model (p = 0.528).

But I do not succeed in extracting the **path coefficients**. 
This is the error i get: `Error in cbind(Xlarge, Xsmall) :  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)`

I already tried (but this did not work):

- standardising my data because of the warning: `Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling`
- adapted my data (threw some NA values away)

This is my modellist:

```
predatielijst = list(

  lmer(plantgrootte ~ gapfraction + olsen_P + (1|plot_ID), data = d),

  glmer(piek1 ~ gapfraction + olsen_P + plantgrootte + (1|plot_ID), 
       family = poisson, data = d),  

      glmer(predatie ~ piek1 + (1|plot_ID), family = binomial, data = d)
)
```

with "predatie" being a binary variable (yes or no) and all the rest continuous variables (gapfraction, plantgrootte, olsen_P & piek1)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `sem.coefs` to extract the path coefficients!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the development version:

`library(devtools)
install_github("jslefche/piecewiseSEM@2.0")`

Replace `list` with `psem` and run the `coefs` or `summary` function. It will likely get rid of your error. If not, open a bug on Github!

WARNING: this will overwrite your current version from CRAN. You will need to reinstall from CRAN to get version 1.4 back.

Comment: There was a problem with the NA values. After removing them, i succeeded in extracting the path coefficients and making the figure with the 'old' package.

Answer (score -1):

try to use lme (out of the nlme library) ilstead of glmer. As far as I understand, the fact that lmer does not provide p-values (while lme does) seems to be the problem here.
Hope this works.

Comment: This does not address the question. The question has nothing to do with p-values and the question is also about the structural equation modeling package piecewiseSEM which isn't addressed in this answer.